# Why the form moving effect is not happening the first time?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm using this code to show a form with a messenger-like popup:

```
  TimeSleep := 5;

  for i := 1 to FormHeight do
  begin
    Form.Top := Form.Top - 1;

    Sleep(TimeSleep);
  end
```

It's working smoothly but only from the second time. I mean I have a button on my form that invokes the loop and the first time I click the form shows suddenly without the sliding effect. If I click again, the effect works.

How can I have it working from the first time?

Thanks.

Comment: When do you make the assignment to TimeSleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not posting enough code to be sure about it, but I assume that your form isn't visible or doesn't even have a window handle before you click the button the first time, so the moving of the form isn't visible. If you insert

```
Form.Show;
Form.Update;
```

before the loop things should work the first time too.  Note the call to `Update()`, it is needed to really show the form that has been made visible in the previous line.

Similarly you should insert a call to `Update()` after the change to the `Top` property inside your loop - it does what the call to `Application.ProcessMessages()` does too, without being such a sledgehammer.  Try to make do without `Application.ProcessMessages()` whenever there is a better way, search Stack Overflow for discussions regarding this.

Two more pieces of advice regarding your loop:

- Movement will not be smooth if anything causes your `Sleep()` to be longer than the 5 milliseconds you request - it's much better to calculate the amount to decrement the top coordinate of the form from the elapsed time since the last movement.
- There is no way anybody will see your form move in 1 pixel increments - the human eye and brain aren't fast enough to gather and process information at that speed, and even cats and insects in your room will only see the 60 or so updates your monitor does in each second.  So a parameter to `Sleep()` of 20 or even 50 is much more sensible than 5. Adjust the form movement accordingly.

**Edit:**

Here is some sample code that creates constant movement of the form even with differing delays:

```
uses
  MMSystem;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm: TForm;
  TicksStart, TicksNow: Longword;
  Progress: Single;
begin
  Frm := TForm.CreateNew(Self);
  try
    // slide a form of 600 by 500 pixel into view over a period of 100 millis
    Frm.SetBounds((Screen.Width - 600) div 2, -500, 600, 500);
    Frm.Show;

    TicksStart := timeGetTime;
    while True do begin
      Sleep(15);
      TicksNow := timeGetTime;
      if TicksNow - TicksStart >= 1000 then
        break;
      Progress := (TicksNow - TicksStart) / 1000;
      Frm.Top := - Round((1.0 - Progress) * 500);
    end;
    Frm.Top := 0;

    Sleep(500);
  finally
    Frm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. You say "it's much better to calculate the amount to decrement the top coordinate of the form from the elapsed time since the last movement." Can you provide me with the corrected code please? And what do you mean by "Adjust the form movement accordingly"? I'm an absolute beginner in Delphi.

Comment: @emurad: You mean you are an absolute beginner in *programming*?

Comment: @emurad: I'm posting some sample code, but given your attitude towards Andreas I was tempted to not do it. His comment may not have been helpful, but your rudeness is still completely inacceptable.

Comment: @emurad: I am sorry, I was a bit unsensitive there.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "Application.ProcessMessages;" before sleep.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. It worked but why the messages are not processed automatically during the first invocation?

Comment: @emurad: Of course they aren't. The code that is being executed in your thread is the code you write. So in a loop in your program, if you want to process messages, you have to do it yourself. (Hint: buy a book about Win32 programming.)